# GLSL Computed Fragment color comes out black despite inputs having correct values

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

My fragment shader is as follows:

```
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;
in float U;
in vec2 UV;
in vec4 vertexNormal_worldSpace;
uniform sampler1D TextureSampler;
uniform sampler2D SandSampler;
uniform vec4 LightPos;
void main()
{
    float cosT = 0.3+clamp(dot(normalize(vertexNormal_worldSpace.xyz),normalize(LightPos.xyz)),0.0,0.7);
    vec3 t = texture(SandSampler,UV).rgb;
    vec3 t2 = texture(TextureSampler,U).rgb;
    color= cosT * t.rgb*t2.rgb;
}
```

In this code, `TextureSampler` is a 256x1 texture, `SandSampler` is a 512x512 texture.

I am expecting the resulting color to be a blend between the colors from `t` and `t2`, multiplied by the value of `cosT` (a value to calculate lighting). Instead, I get all black. I have tested `cosT`, `t.rgb` and `t2.rgb` to confirm they  contain the correct values and display independently as intended, and I have also checked that my UV coordinates are correct. I can combine `cosT` and `t2.rgb` to produce a correct result: `color= cosT * t2.rgb;` or I can simply have `color = t.rgb;` which also produces a correct result, however including `t.rgb` in any way results in an all black result.

The code `color = vec3(cosT,t.g,0);` produces the correct value of `cosT` in the red component, however no green is visible whatsoever. The code `color = vec3(0,t.g,0);` then produces the correct green component of my texture.

Comment: This is just a random guess: Could it be that it has something to do with uniform locations? If you only use t but not cosT, then the LightPos uniform might get optimized away. I could, for example, imaging a case where you override the SandSampler uniform when you try to set LightPos. Similar things could also happen with varyings (vertexNormal_worldSpace optimized away when cosT not used).

Comment: Is your code perhaps assuming the location of TextureSampler is 0 and SandSampler is 1 because that's the order of declaration?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: I don't think I could simplify this code any further since all of it is directly related to the problem I am having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, the issue was with my code for binding the textures rather than the shader itself, which somehow worked with one texture at a time but not with 2 textures. The code:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D,TextureID);
glUniform1i(TextureID,0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,SandTextureID);
glUniform1i(SandTextureID,1);
```

By changing the value in `glBindTexture` :

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D,Texture);
glUniform1i(TextureID,0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,SandTexture);
glUniform1i(SandTextureID,1);
```

The code now works. I was passing the uniform location into the texture, rather than the texture location, which resulted in strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've tested `cosT`, `t.rgb`, and `t2.rgb`. Well if these are indeed correct, we need to look at the last line:

```
color= cosT * t.rgb*t2.rgb;
```

The reason your color is black *must* be because the RGB values are being set to zero.
*<sub>Alternatively, it could be due to code that wasn't posted causing these fragments to fail [per-sample operations & tests](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Per-Sample_Processing), or perhaps you're running into one of those wacky vendor-specific limitations for your fragment shader. But I'm going to trust that the problem is in the fragment shader...</sub>*

Your first assignment for `cosT` is limiting its values between 0 and 1.  This is fine.

My bets are that your issue lies with this multiplication:

```
t.rgb*t2.rgb;
```

According to [GLSL operators](http://learnwebgl.brown37.net/12_shader_language/glsl_mathematical_operations.html), you're performing a component-wise vector multiplication, so:

```
t.rgb*t2.rgb = (t.r * t2.r, t.g * t2.g, t.b *t2.b)
```

Now, what would this do? Assuming your RGB colors fall in the range `[0..1]`, then you are always going to end up with a smaller value (e.g. `0.1 * 0.7 = 0.07`).

Furthermore, if you multiply that smaller value by a another number, `cosT`, which will be between `[0..1]`, then the result is even closer to 0. If not already black, it will be close.

---

When you say you need to blend your colors, my belief is that component-wise vector multiplication is ***NOT*** what you want.

Instead consider using the [`mix` function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) or using a weighted average. This will interpolate your colors.

Comment: In this case, I do want component-wise multiplication, since my 1D texture is a gradient and my 2D texture is a grayscale texture, I am hoping for a textured effect over a gradient. Using `mix()` gives the expected result for `mix(t,t2,0.5)` but then multiplying this by `cosT` removes the component given by `t` again. `cosT` is definitely not 0, since I have limited it to `[0.3,1]`. Using a color picker on a screenshot shows that the pixels are completely black, even when both of my textures have been set to _completely white_ so even in a worst case, I should get a dark gray.